# How to post a gallery-image on a users wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Our app uses the PHP- aswell as the JS-SDK of Facebook. We are able to access the users-images and the images of his friends thru both sdks. The upload of photos into user-albums works aswell.

The user currently selects one of his images which gets manipulated on our server and uploaded to Facebook into the album it came from. That part works. We now want to post that uploaded image onto the users wall. Facebook itself generates a post on the users feed about newly uploaded images (can be disabled on the uploading request) but those posts are not customizable. The standard facebook-post request requires an url to the optional photo. The documentaton states that it is not allowed to link to images from the facebook content delivery-network (which has been confirmed by the graph api as it throws an appropriate error).

Is it possible to create a standard wall-post that contains a gallery-image somehow? Ideally it would use the gallery-popup but that is clearly super-nice-to-have.

An externally hosted copy is an (unwanted) workaround that we already know. Reuploading the image is an option as long as it does not show up in the gallery twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Simple solution :**

Get a tinyurl for you fbcdn'ed picture through tinyurl api:

Example with url from above :

```
http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=http://a4.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc3/13943_196960329960_683709960_2997879_7206516_n.jpg
```

Returns :

```
http://tinyurl.com/3ta96kh
```

Then use this url as the "picture", I tried it here and it works ! : http://jsfiddle.net/dwarfy/VYAeD/27/

There was another solution [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/how-to-post-to-a-users-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iphone-app) but It seems facebook corrected it and it still says the error with facebook CDN when I post using https://graph.facebook.com/PICTURE_ID as picture instead of the FBCDN image url.

I think it's the best solution ...

My example doesn't use the link parameter but you could set it to the gallery image ...

Comment: With this you don't have to have a copy of the image on your server and you don't have to do the redirect by yourself, BUT it makes a public link to your image .. which is maybe not really good regarding privacy

Comment: Anyway there is also a "public link" to any image in the FBCDN, it's just that we cannot find those urls I guess ..

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you can't post to users' walls image saved on fb BUT also you don't have to save it physically on you server. if you want to post an image, for example:

http://a4.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc3/13943_196960329960_683709960_2997879_7206516_n.jpg

facebook as you know will not accept this. but ther is no problem to post something like this: http://yourserver.com/script.php?image=a4.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc3/13943_196960329960_683709960_2997879_7206516_n.jpg (without http:// -- its important, if you include http:// facebook will find out what's going - and we don't want it:)

script.php is a php file on your server that do this:

```
<?
    $url = "http://".$_GET['image'];
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    echo file_get_contents($url);   
?>
```

or something like this:

```
<?
    $url = "http://".$_GET['image'];
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($url);
    //some image modifications here//
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    echo imagejpeg($image, null, 100);
?>
```

you can also add an database with urls and post something like this: http://yourserver.com/script.php?imageid=ID hiding all images' real paths.

---

If you want to save on traffic after publishing images on walls just redirect:

```
<?
    //if published then just redirect
    $url = "http://".$_GET['image'];
    header('Location: '.$url); die();
?>
```

Comment: Interesting idea tho I still have to 'provide' all images in terms of traffic. Your first suggestion would work for any url so anyone could use our server to proxy requests. So I have to secure the system somehow like in your third example. That will cause even more overhead cause we'd have to use a database. Storing the images on our server is still the fastest and easiest way even tho it is not an option. +1 for the creativity

Comment: after publishing (when thumbnails on fb are already created) you can switch from file_get_contents($url) to redirect: header('Location: $url'); die();

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the copy of that image otherwise there is no way you can use this image in standard post dialog.

Use PHP function

```
copy()
```

I know you are looking for any other alternative but to create a spare image on your server or any other server is the only solution.

Comment: As I said: Having an external copy of that image is an unwanted solution. Copying the image is not part of the problem.

Comment: Yes and I write "You have to make the copy of that image otherwise there is no way you can use this image".

Comment: I don't need to copy those images. We already have the images on our server because we did create them.